# $env:Path is truncated in powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-7

Looking at my system variable PATH in Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Environment Variables ...the final value is:

`C:\Users\bmackey\AppData\Roaming\npm`

When I run `$env:Path.split(";")` in powershell the last value is:

`C:\Program F`

The last 76 characters are truncated in my powershell output.  Only the first 1951 characters are displayed.  This suddenly happened this morning.  I am unable to run a program that requires the last line in my `$env:PATH` that is being truncated.

Why did this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Wow. You have a lot in your path-variable! Are sure the program fails because of it? Does it display everything if you run `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path")` ?

Comment: What is the last value in the array produced by Split?

Comment: @dugas Did you read the question? :-)

Comment: @FrodeF. - yes, I read the question. He mentioned the output was truncated, he didn't mention what the last value of the array was.

Comment: Really? "When I run $env:Path.split(";") in powershell the last value is: C:\Program F"  .  That was the last value, and he's missing 76 chars after that because it was truncated

Comment: Yes @FrodeF, really. I was trying to determine if he meant the last line of the output returned or the actual value in the array.

Comment: @dugas - Sorry I'm not sure what you are asking.  What array?

Comment: The array returned by Split: $paths = $env:Path.split(";"); $paths[$paths.Length - 1];

Comment: The last line in powershell is the last thing returned by the split array.  It should have 3-4 more elements in the array that are not there; the last 76 characters.

Answer (score 1):

SUPER LAME yet totally true answer: I restarted my computer and the problem went away.  I ran `$env:Path.split(";")` and I got the full path.  My program (ember) works again.  Ugh.

Comment: Path variables between 2048 and 4096 bytes (chars) requires a restart to take effect if I'm not wrong. Did you change it ? If so you should have included that in the question.  :-)

Comment: No I didn't change it.  It's possible something I installed changed it.